# MVC Append database record to table after deletion

Tags: c#, mysql, ajax

I have an MVC application that will list names. The names are in an entity framework database. A timer is beside the first name in the list and when the timer ends,  the name is removed from the list and the database (this continues until no names are left). The application starts by displaying 5 names from the database. I am having a hard time when the first name is removed, how to append  the next name in the database to the table.

for example: if records 1,2,3,4,5 are displaying and record 1 is removed, I Need records 2,3,4,5,6 to display. This is the code I have as of now.

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<RangeTimer.Models.UserName>

@{
      ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">

<h2>Add Title</h2>

<p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add Name to list for range time", "AddUserName", new{ target = "_blank" })
    </p>


<hr />


<table class="table" id="NameList">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>
        <th>
            Time Remaining
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td id="FullName">

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
            </td>

            @Html.HiddenFor((modelItem => item.Id))
            <td>

                <span id="timer"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

</div>
<br/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    startTimer();
    function startTimer() {
        $('#timer').countdown({
            layout: '{mnn} : {snn}', timeSeparator: ':', until: 15, onTick: TimerColorChange, onExpiry: restartTimer
        });
    }


    function restartTimer() {

        var Id = $("#item_Id").val();
        $('#timer').countdown('destroy');

        //we delete the table's Info
        $('#FullName').parent().remove();

        // deleting records from entity framweork database;
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "UserNames")',
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ Id: Id }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //repopulate list
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    row += "<tr><td>" + item.FullName + "</td></tr>";
                });
                alert(FullName).val();
                $('#NameList').html(row);
                $('#NameList > tbody:last-child').append("<tr><td>"+ $('#FullName').val()+"</td> </tr>");
              // $('#NameList').html(data);
            }

        });


        startTimer();

    }


    function TimerColorChange(periods) {
        var seconds = $.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods);
        if (seconds <= 3) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "black");
        }
    }

});

 </script>
```

Controller:

```
 public class UserNamesController : Controller
{
    private UserNameDBContext db = new UserNameDBContext();


    // GET: UserNames
    public ActionResult Index()
    {        

        return View(db.UserNames.Take(5).ToList());
    }

    // GET: AddEmployee  
    public ActionResult AddUserName()
    {        
        return View();
    }

    //Post method to add details    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUserName(UserName obj)
    {
        AddDetails(obj);
        TempData["Message"] = obj.FullName + " has been added to the list successfully.";
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }


    private void AddDetails(UserName obj)
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GetAddName  @FullName", new SqlParameter("@FullName", obj.FullName));
    }


      [HttpPost]      
    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        //try
        //{
            // TODO: Add delete logic here
            UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(Id);
            db.UserNames.Remove(userName);
            db.SaveChanges();
        //return View(db.UserNames.Take(5).ToList());
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
         }


    }
```

Comment: OK well how to refresh the page after changes in the database will all depend on server and client communication. The timer for example, is it a JavaScript timer or a C# timer?

Comment: The timer code is in the script tags in the index.cshtml file. It is using jquery

Comment: Right there are at least two ways you could go about refreshing the data; the simplest, though not the most elegant way, would be to simply redirect back to the same page when the time ends, but this would cause a full page reload and not a very good UX. Another way would be to use jQuery to remove the <tr/> from the DOM that contains the information for the user that was removed from the db, this one could be done without a full reload but may happen quickly enough for users not to notice so may want some visual clue it's happened...

Comment: I have tried the page reload and it makes it very obvious. The way I have it now, removes from the table and the database which is perfect. I just cant get the next record to append.

Comment: I see, you can adjust the jQuery that sends the request to the server (to remove the name) to include details of the newly appended record in the db to the response from the server and then use these new record details to append a new <tr /> to the display table with jQuery.

Comment: Can you give example? Thanks for the information

Comment: I will add a way of achieving this, only it differs ever so slightly in that it uses ajax to retrieve the list of user names rather than supplying them on page load via the view model. I'm not sure your exact requirements so this might not be suitable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes should give you the desired behaviour, however, the update is pretty quick so the change between a row being removed and a new row added will likely go unnoticed (but that is an easy problem to sort with a loading animation).

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult GetNames()
 {
    return Json(db.UserNames.Take(5).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
 {
     // delete user:
     UserName userName = db.UserNames.Find(id);
     db.UserNames.Remove(userName);
     db.SaveChanges();

     // TODO: find new user here and return as JSON:
     return Json(new UserName { FullName = "User 6", Id = 6 });
 }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<table class="table" id="NameList">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Full Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Time Remaining
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>

 $(function () {

            var usersList = [];

            function init() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "UserNames")',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {

                        var row = null,
                            first = true,
                            timer = null;

                        // populate local users list:
                        usersList = data;

                        // populate HTML for table:
                        $.each(usersList, function (index, item) {
                            row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.Id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');

                            // add a timer to the first row:
                            if (first) {
                                $(row).append(getTimer());
                                first = false;
                            }

                            $('#NameList').append(row);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });        
            }
            init();

            function restartTimer() {

                var deletedElement = null,
                    nextId = null,            
                    newRow = null,
                    row = null,
                    that = this;

                    // remove the deleted item from local array:
                    deletedElement = usersList.shift();

                    // delete record from db on server:
                    $.ajax({

                        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "UserNames")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({ id: deletedElement.Id }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {

                            // remove this timer:
                            $(that).remove();

                            // add new record to local array:
                            usersList.push(data);

                            // add html for row:
                            newRow = $('<tr id="row-' + data.Id + '"><td>' + data.FullName + '</td></tr>');
                            $('#NameList').append(newRow);

                            //remove the html for deleted user:
                            $('#row-' + deletedElement.Id).remove();

                            if (usersList.length > 0) {

                                // get the next item id:
                                nextId = usersList[0].Id;

                                // add a timer to the new item:
                                row = $('#row-' + nextId);
                                row.append(getTimer());
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }

            function getTimer() {
                var timer = $('<td></td>');
                $(timer).countdown({
                    layout: '{mnn} : {snn}', timeSeparator: ':', until: 15, onTick: TimerColorChange, onExpiry: restartTimer
                });
                return timer;
            }

            function TimerColorChange(periods) {

                var seconds = $.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods);
                if (seconds <= 3) {
                    $(this).css("color", "red");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("color", "black");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I got this to work with adding the new record with static data but not with the data from the database. Thank you for your assistance.